# AutoComment from trivial answer - ability to override?

Tags: feature-request, automatic-comments

Sometimes the answer is trivial, why are short answers being demoted to comments?

I wonder if this behaviour is promoting comments over answers - is that something we're trying to achieve?

Could I ask for an ability to override this behaviour?

Comment: Short does not equate to trivial e= m(c*c) - it bothers me a bit when it does this.

Comment: Linking to an answer in a different question *is not an answer*.

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted? It's a good question, even if the answer is *no*. I thought that it was a good idea to post links to previous questions, because the way google works popular questions would span this kind of web, and therefore there's nothing wrong with a short answer. And since comments aren't really answers... Potato tomato, but this is a GOOD question, dammnit - Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This *only* applies to answers that consist of a bare link to other Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange questions with very little other descriptive text.

> Could I ask for an ability to override this behaviour?

You have it -- elaborate and explain a bit more in your answer and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I thought this behaviour applied to all short link answers  :o)

Comment: This begs me to consider why it does not also automatically add a `close as duplicate` if the comment would get upvoted :)

Comment: @Mark - Because the link isn't necessarily a dupe. It could just be a pointer to some related info.

Comment: @razlebe but isn't that what human interaction is for? I mean, you see it as automarked as duplicate, you see it's not, end of story.

Comment: @Kheldar - someone upvoting a link doesn't necessarily mean they agree it's a dupe. I think this approach would result in a flurry of bad `closed as duplicate` questions. If people see the link is a dupe, they have the ability to vote to close as normal.

Comment: Meh, so turning an otherwise valid short answer into a link instead of appending a `as can be seen [here](http://http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104404/146482)` is better?

Answer (score 11):

I guess we are talking about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242499/what-are-the-best-classes-to-play-online-audio-video-in-ios

In that case, your answer is not an answer, it is a comment. It's not helpful in any way and you're linking against an unrelated question (the same question twice, by the way). Additionally you filled the answer with nonsense (Lorem Ipsum)(to fool the system) and answered an question which should be closed instead, because it is not a real question.

The system is working and was triggered on your answer for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew - You just have to add one or more sentences and it's not tranfering to comment anymore. It is to force you to describe your answer little bit more